# How does a CIC filter output meet Nyquist?

Tags: lowpass-filter, nyquist

In this image from [Understanding cascaded integrator-comb filters](https://www.embedded.com/understanding-cascaded-integrator-comb-filters/)

The bottom image shows the output response, with the entire range as passband:

[image]

Even the CIC compensation filters are all passband to $f_s/2$.

Also on the same page:

[image]

As opposed to a ['normal' LPF](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-020-2140-6), which has the passband end at some point < $f_s/2$:

[image]

How does a CIC output response meet Nyquist? If there is no clear stopband, surely the frequencies are all folding into each other and making a mess? or am I missing something?

Comment: [A Beginner's Guide To Cascaded Integrator-Comb (CIC) Filters](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1337.php)

Comment: *//How does a CIC output response meet Nyquist?//*  What do you mean by *"meet Nyquist"* ?  Filters aren't quite the same as input signals.  *//If there is no clear stopband, surely the frequencies are all folding into each other and making a mess?//*  Isn't that also the case for other filters?  Like a HPF?

Answer (score 3):

As the author of the linked article, I will try to answer your question. But first, let’s step back and understand the purpose of CIC filters. CIC filters are used in applications requiring very narrowband linear-phase lowpass filtering. In such applications you might implement a tapped-delay line FIR filter having a one or two hundred taps. Now if you initially filter your signal with CIC filter followed by a tapped-delay line FIR filter, then that follow-on FIR filter many only require dozens of taps. This scheme provides a greatly reduced lowpass filtering computational workload because single-stage CIC filter only implements two additions per input sample. And that’s the idea behind my article’s Figure 1.

user37216, you are correct that the lowpass filter in your last image has a clearly defined passband. And CIC filters have no clearly defined passband, but rather they have that “drooping” mainlobe centered at zero Hz. Keep in mind, for high valued decimation factors (large ‘D’) a decimating CIC filter’s mainlobe will be much more narrow, relative to the input signal’s sample rate, than the mainlobes in my article’s Figure 6(A) and Figure 8(A).

If my original lowpass filter application required a two-sided passband of B Hz then that B-Hz passband is the green-shaded band (centered at zero Hz) shown at the top your first image (my article’s Figure 6(A)). Notice that the frequency of fs/2 Hz (what you call “Nyquist”) is at the far right side of that image.

But also keep in mind that the frequency magnitude response in my article’s Figure 6(A) is BEFORE any downsampling (decimation) is performed. After downsampling by eight is performed the resultant frequency magnitude response is that shown in my article’s Figure 6(B) where the passband is B Hz. And now a traditional (tapped-delay line) follow-on lowpass FIR filter will need a passband of B Hz and sufficient attenuation above B Hz. And again, the follow-on FIR filter will require far fewer taps than if the CIC filter was not used. I hope what I’ve written here makes sense. If not, please ask additional questions of me.